# Return either xml or json from MVC web api based on request returns 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using the URL`http://localhost/api/Student` I get a list of students in XML format.

What I would like to do is have the option to return either json or xml based on the request. So for json, it would be;

```
http://localhost/api/Student.json
```

and for XML, it would be;

```
http://localhost/api/Student.xml
```

likewise;

```
http://localhost/api/Student.json/1/
http://localhost/api/Student.xml/1/
```

I have implemented this in my `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

```
 StructuremapWebApi.Start();


 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
 config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "text/xml");
 // Web API routes
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "DefaultApi",
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "Api UriPathExtension ID",
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{ext}",
 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, extension = 
 RouteParameter.Optional }
 );

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "Api UriPathExtension",
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{extension}/{id}",
 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, extension = 
 RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Once I call one of the links with the extension it returns a `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`.

Am I missing something? Any help please.

Comment: the ext for the controller or parameter, i think  must be like : ``api/{controller}.{ext}/{id}``

Comment: Implemented but doesnt work, still returns 404

Comment: APIs should not be using extension in url. You can either have a parameter in the API url to indicate which format to return or send Accept header in the request to decide which format to return.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a dotnet developer but my guess is that `AddUriPathExtensionMapping` isn't doing what you think it's doing. I assume your routes aren't getting registered with the `.json` or `.xml` file types like you think which is why you get a 404.

So you'll either have to figure out how to add the pattern matching you need the proper way or take another approach.

Usually the way an API supports multiple formats is through HTTP headers.

For JSON the client will send the headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accepts: application/json
```

For XML, typically this:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accepts: application/xml
```

Assuming that you still want to send a JSON body to your API when sending POSTs, PUTs or PATCHes but simply expect to receive the response in XML format. If you wanted to send over XML then you'd change `Content-Type` to `application/xml`

Of course, you have to support these headers yourself server-side, usually by adding middleware that serializes the responses and requests to and from the format that you need.